# Connecting CodeIgniter in MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

// Generally localhost
$config['host'] = "dbh75.mongolab.com";
// Generally 27017
$config['port'] = 27757;
// The database you want to work on
$config['db'] = "rms";
// Required if Mongo is running in auth mode
$config['user'] = "arny";
$config['pass'] = "arny";

/*  
 * Defaults to FALSE. If FALSE, the program continues executing without waiting for a database response. 
 * If TRUE, the program will wait for the database response and throw a MongoCursorException if the update did not succeed.
*/
$config['query_safety'] = TRUE;

//If running in auth mode and the user does not have global read/write then set this to true
$config['db_flag'] = TRUE;

//consider these config only if you want to store the session into mongoDB
//They will be used in MY_Session.php
$config['sess_use_mongo'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_collection_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
```

Do I need to copy this code and overwrite the database of the codeIgniter or do I only need to call this file?

Comment: Does it work if you just call the file? How about if you add your own database's details in there?

Comment: @andrewsi - i always get this error everytime i want to add data on mongodb **Undefined property: Signup::$mongo_db** - i have edit the data there and i also added that file in the config/autoload. i really don't know whats wrong. anyways i'm still a newbie programmer hehe :)